# Read a Google spreadsheet from an Android app and list out that data?

Tags: android, json, google-apps-script

I am working on a Android app to read/write data on a google sheet. I am okay with the write part but read operation only displays a blank screen with no error thrown. It would be helpful if there is a "latest" fine working android program to read data from a google sheet.

Comment: Google has [documentation for Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api). There is a [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) page and [Reading & Writing guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values). If that does not help, please post some code and the error message (if any).

Comment: I will take a look, Tigger.

Comment: How to call the range names in the program?

Comment: After a glance on Google Api v4 to read a Google sheet, I am stuck with the part of calling the range in the program. [ // Range names ] part in the code above. Appreciate help! - [ I am a newt to Android programming ]. Is there any working code for reading a google spreadsheet using api v4?

Comment: Finally, after a huge time spent, I fixed the "read" operation of Google sheet. Below is the code which I worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ListofCars extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ListView listView;
SimpleAdapter adapter;
ProgressDialog loading;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.carslist);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listof_cars);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    getItems();
}


private void getItems() {
   
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "please wait", false, true);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
 "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxOLElujQcy1- 
  ZUer1KgEvK16gkTLUqYftApjNCM_IRTL3HSuDk/exec? 
  id=YOUR_SPREAD_SHEET_IDHERE&sheet=YOURSHEETNAMEHERE",

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    parseItems(response);
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   
                }
            }


    );

    int socketTimeOut = 50000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeOut, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);

    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(stringRequest);

}

void parseItems(String jsonResponse) {
    
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
        JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("listofcars");

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            
            JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String car = jo.getString("car");
            String type = jo.getString("type");
            
            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
            item.put("car", car);
            item.put("type", type);
  
            list.add(item);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,list, R.layout.list_item_row,
    new String[]{"car","type"},new int[]{R.id.car_name,R.id.car_type});

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    loading.dismiss();
    
}

public void onItemClick(@Nullable AdapterView<?> parent, @Nullable 
View view, int position, long id) {
   
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cardetails.class);
    HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
   
    String car = map.get("car");
    String type = map.get("type");

    intent.putExtra("car",car);
    intent.putExtra("type",type);

    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {}}
```

`

Comment: Paste your respective [SPREADSHEETID] and [SHEETNAME] in the above code closer to the "GET" keyword. Create corresponding (xml) activity for your app with Textviews. Here the response from the sheet is JSON and the JSON is parsed back to display the values in Android app.

Comment: The columns in the google sheet and the strings constants to which we assign the values[i.e column car to string car] are named a same name for easy understanding.